# swift 2.2 basic, if statement doesn't compile

Tags: swift

Pardon me for beginner's question, Why this code got complained about `{ expected after if`, the braces are already there

```
var years = Int(edtYears.text!)    
if years !=nil {
    //do something
}else {
    //...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add space between both side of condition like `if years != nil {` or you can also write without space but the both side `if years!=nil {`

```
var years = Int("")

if years != nil {
    //do something
}else {
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never do like this. Make sure you do optional chaining otherwise you will surely get a crash.

```
if let text = edtYears.text, let convertToInt = Int(text){
   print("Int \(convertToInt)")
}else{
   print("Cannot convert")
}
```